# Android System Bar not hiding in Android video full-screen on expo-av

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-av

So I’m using `expo-av` on my app to play videos. And I’m running into an issue on Android where the Android System Navigation bar doesn’t hide in full-screen mode. I’ve even tried using `SystemNavigationBar` from `react-native-system-navigation-bar` to try and show/hide it like so:

```
const onFullscreenUpdate = async ({ fullscreenUpdate }: VideoFullscreenUpdateEvent) => {
  switch (fullscreenUpdate) {
    case VideoFullscreenUpdate.PLAYER_WILL_PRESENT:
      await SystemNavigationBar.navigationHide();
      break;
    …
    case VideoFullscreenUpdate.PLAYER_DID_DISMISS:
      await SystemNavigationBar.navigationShow();
      break;
  }
};
```

Even then, when I do `playerRef.current?.presentFullscreenPlayer()`, the System Navigation Bar doesn’t hide. Is there something in the library that forces this bar to show? Any help is appreciated.